# applying UI button() method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a dynamic text field and button. I want to apply UI button method on button but it is not working. Below is my code.

```
this.marketSymbolAddDialogObject
    = $('<b>Symbol:</b> <input type="text" id="symbolName" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></input>'+
        '<button id="add_symbol">Add Symbol</button>'
        );    
var bt = this.marketSymbolAddDialogObject.find("button");
bt.button(); // **Not working**
```

what exactle i am doing wrong in it. I have also tried this 
    $("#add_symbol").button()
but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually add the element to the DOM first before the find will work, I believe.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was also thinking of this solution to add the elements to the DOM first then it should work and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

"button" is not a descendent of `this.marketSymbolAddDialogObject` so doing a `find()` on it will result in 0 matched elements. Use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
var bt = this.marketSymbolAddDialogObject.filter("button");
```

**find():**

> Description: Get the **descendants** of
>   each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a
>   selector, jQuery object, or element.

**filter():**

> Description: Reduce the set of **matched
>   elements** to those that match the
>   selector or pass the function's test.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the jquery`s 'button' function, but you may find useful to append your jquery created DOM elements:

```
this.marketSymbolAddDialogObject
= $('<b>Symbol:</b> <input type="text" id="symbolName" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></input>'+
    '<button id="add_symbol">Add Symbol</button>'
    ).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: `button()` is a function of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), a common plugin for jQuery. It just makes normal `<input type="submit">` and `<input type="button">` elements "pretty".